# Vertx 3.4: Difference between running code immediately and context.runOnContext

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to figure out the basics of **Vertx**. I was going through standard doc on it [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_context_object), where I stumbled upon a section on **context object**. It says that it lets you run your code **later** by providing a method called `runOnContext`. The thing I don't understand is, in which case would I choose to invoke a (non-blocking) block of code later? If the code is non-blocking, it will take same amount of time, whether you execute it now or later.

Can anyone please tell me, in which case, `context.runOnContext` will be helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most often it will be helpful if you call it from another thread. It will schedule a task for execution by the event loop bound to this context.

If you're already on the event loop, you may also use it when you read items from a queue: instead of processing all items as a single event, you would schedule an event per item in the queue. That would give other kind of events (network, filesystem) a chance to be processed earlier.

Comment: Can you show an example for the second point you're making? I would have said the same thing, but I tried it and it doesn't actually work. Breaking a CPU bound task into smaller chunks and scheduling individually still blocks HTTP requests for example until all the processing is done (or I'm doing it wrong). The first point you're making is correct of course, but it's not the use case that the linked docs are showing.

Comment: Maybe it was a problem in your code. If you run ```Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    Context context = vertx.getOrCreateContext();
    context.runOnContext(v1 -> {
      System.out.println("One");
      context.runOnContext(v2 -> {
        System.out.println("Two");
      });
      System.out.println("Three");
    });
``` you'll see: "One, Three, Two"

Comment: No, it works, I'm not disputing this. What I'm saying is "give other kind of events (network, filesystem) a chance to be processed earlier" is not actually the case. If you increase your code to runOnContext from 3 to a significantly large number, and fire up a httpserver in parallel, all http requests stall until all your runOnContext calls have completed. Maybe I should write my own question to illustrate this with sample code...

Comment: How, now I understand. Tasks are processed in order so if your submit a bunch of task with runOnContext and eventually start a HTTP server then, yes, the HTTP server events will be handled after the tasks.

Comment: How do we know if "we are on the event loop or not"?

Comment: `Vertx.currentContext().isOnEventLoopThread()`. Beware that `currentContext` may return null if you're not on a Vert.x thread.